# Does php script slow down when echoing mysql queries to screen during loop

Tags: php, mysql

If I have a loop that inserts data into a mysql table, does me echoing the query to the screen slow down the script enough to make a significant difference?

```
for ($a=1;$a<=10000;$a++){
   $ins = "INSERT into (number) values (".$a.")";
   $stmt = $db->query($ins);
   echo $ins."\n";
}
```

Comment: No, it won't slow you down. INSERTS are time-consuming, especially if there are indexes on the table.

Comment: why not to save in an array and then use INSERT at once outside the loop

Comment: now u have 2 solutions , check them

Comment: did you checked the solution? check them and accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually for your case echoing is not very much time consuming but inserting a single column value with iteration e.g 10K times is somewhat time consuming and for your case your inserting 10K rows for one column inside loop. You can insert multiple row with a single query like this way-

```
INSERT INTO number(a) VALUES (4),(6),(7);
```

> With MYSQL, You can include multiple lists of column values, each enclosed
>   within parentheses and separated by commas

More specifically, something like this-

```
$numbers = [];
for ($a=1;$a<=10000;$a++){
  $numbers[] = '('.$a.')';
}

$b = implode(",", $numbers);
$ins = "INSERT into (number) values $b";
$stmt = $db->query($ins);
echo $ins."\n";
```

Comment: Little correction: `(".$b.")` this will generated values like (1,2,3,4) instead of (1),(2),(3) ....

Comment: @devpro agreed, let me edit, I'm just doing that :) mate

Answer (score 0):

INSERT `10000` rows in `10000` iteration will take time not `echo` the query, actually.

I suggest you to store values into an array like:

```
<?php
$yourArray = array();
for ($a=1;$a<=10000;$a++){
   $yourArray[] = $a;
}
?>
```

Then, outside the loop use `implode()` for comma seperated values

```
<?php
$yourQuery = "INSERT into (number) values ";
$yourQuery .= "("; // for starting bracket
$yourQuery .= implode("),(",$yourArray);
$yourQuery .= ")"; // for ending bracket
?>
```